# Can there be more than one set of MFA questions asked during the discoverAndAddAccounts process?

Tags: .net, aggregation, intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

I am using discoverAndAddAccountsResponse to answer the first set of MFA challenge questions, but this method only returns an AccountList.

Is there ever a situation where I should expect more MFA questions in response to the first set of MFA questions, and if so, how should I implement that process?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - see this page for more information - http://docs.developer.intuit.com/0020_Aggregation_Categorization_Apps/0005_Service_Features/Multi-Factor_Authentication.

Comment: Then in what situation would you use the discoverAndAddAccountsResponse method?

Comment: Answered here: [stackoverflow.com/questions/16192453](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16192453/under-what-situation-would-the-discoverandaddaccountsresponse-method-in-ipp-aggc)