# Under what situation would the discoverAndAddAccountsResponse method in IPP AggCat be used?

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

I understand to verify that a bank is not asking more than one set of MFA questions, you must check the results from each discoverAndAddAccounts call, but IPP AggCat for .Net also offers the discoverAndAddAccountsResponse method. Can this method also pass back the new Challenge/Response questions? If so, how, and if not, when would this method ever be used?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The latest release, 1.3.0, has an additional overload to DiscoverAndAddAccountsResponse that passes back challenge questions and session to handle multiple MFA rounds.  Please see:

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_aggregation_categorization_apps/devkits

Comment: This link does not explain how the NEW Challenge/Response questions are returned from the discoverAndAddAccountsResponse method. I am asking specifically about the **discoverAndAddAccountsResponse** method, _not_ the **discoverAndAddAccounts** method.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. I await the release.

Comment: Still waiting on this release (.Net).  This question also applies to the **UpdateInstitutionLoginResponse** method.

Comment: @Sundance, sorry for the confusion.  I updated my answer above with the latest release.